# How to execute a script using sudo when it resides on an SSHFS mount?

Tags: sudo, sshfs

I am not asking about mounting the SSHFS mountpoint, which is the topic of all the similar questions I found.

My mountpoint (`/path/to/sshfs/mount/`) is correctly mounted and I can list, read, write all expected files as my user.

I do have permissions to copy the script to a local directory. However, because the script requires several subdirectories containing library files and resources, I prefer to execute the script where it resides rather than copy it locally. Also, it does not **need** to be copied to the local machine to do its intended job.

Unfortunately for the SSHFS mount, the script requires root permissions for many operations because it must install some files to system directories and update files of different users existing in the system.

Here's my error:

```
$ cd /path/to/sshfs/mount/
$ sudo ./myscript.sh
sudo: unable to execute ./myscript.sh: Permission denied
```

Here are the checks I performed:

```
$ ls -la
-rwxr-x--- 1 myuser team   8173 Dec 15 06:33 myscript.sh

$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for myuser:
#

$ cat /etc/fstab
myuser@myserver:/path/to/sshfs/mount/ /path/to/sshfs/mount/  fuse.sshfs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,user,follow_symlinks,identityfile=/path/to/.ssh/key_file,allow_other,default_permissions   0 2
```

This shows that the required fuse.conf option is enabled:

```
$ cat /etc/fuse.conf
user_allow_other
```

What SSHFS configuration will allow me to run:

```
$ sudo /path/to/sshfs/mount/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Does the answer given here https://serverfault.com/questions/736523/sshfs-permission-denied-even-for-root-user help?

Comment: @fuzzydrawings: That accepted answer seems to say it is not possible unless you are able to change the server sshd security, which I cannot do. The server is ssh hardened.

Comment: Maybe this idea is worth trying: https://serverfault.com/questions/158392/how-do-i-sudo-over-sshfs/873259#873259

Comment: What does the line relating to `/path/to/sshfs/mount/` in `mount`'s output say?

Comment: @fra-san - `mount -vvv /path/to/sshfs/mount/` succeeds and gives no output. Did you mean `findmnt`? `/path/to/sshfs/mount myuser@myserver:/path/to/sshfs/mount/ fuse.sshfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other`

Comment: @fra-san: I see I need to add `exec` to the mount options. Thank you. Testing now...

Comment: @fra-san: adding `exec` mount option is the solution. If you want to provide an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @MountainX I meant just `mount`, as in, e.g., `mount | grep '/path/to/sshfs/mount/'`. I'd encourage you to post an answer yourself with your findings. Right now I wouldn't know where the default options for sshfs mounts in `fstab` come from (noting that, at least on my system, mounting by means of the `sshfs` command doesn't add the `noexec` option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the mount command supports `exec` and `noexec` mount options:

- exec: Permit execution of binaries.
- noexec: Do not permit direct execution of any binaries on the mounted filesystem.

Even if you do not specify either of those mount options, the `noexec` mount option will be applied if you specify the `users` mount option.

- users: Allow any user to mount and to unmount the filesystem, even when some other ordinary user mounted it.

**The users option implies the options noexec, nosuid, and nodev** (unless overridden by subsequent options, as in the option line users,exec,dev,suid).

This command shows that `noexec` was being applied implicitly:

```
findmnt /path/to/sshfs/mount  
myuser@myserver:/path/to/sshfs/mount/ fuse.sshfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other
```

Therefore, the solution to this question was simply to add the `exec` mount option.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are somewhat confused about permissions.

Your sshfs access can only access files as the user whom authenticated the ssh session. While, as MountainX says, the filesystem is probably mounted as noexec, that is trivial to work around:

```
$ sudo bash myscript.sh
```

However, do be aware that while the script will execute as root on the local machine with root's privileges, it will only have the permissions of the ssh authenticating user on the remote filesystem. Further shell scripts usually just string together other commands - some of those might be relative paths which map correctly to the sshfs mount point. Others may point elsewhere; this looks like an accident waiting to happen.

Comment: The issue is already solved. See my answer.

Comment: You have one solution which solved your immediate issue - you created a very fragile system which will blow up in your face.

Comment: I do not see how adding the "exec" mount option is "a very fragile system which will blow up in your face." Please explain better.

Comment: Explained above - you are spanning trust domains and complicating dependency management.

Comment: It was not explained clearly. But your comment reveals the principles behind your answer. Of course those are valid in general, but IMO they do not apply here. This is a simple installer script. It performs no actions on the remote system. Given its design and purpose I would argue that running it this way enhances reliability, simplifies dependency management, and honors trust domains.